# If else statement does't work in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Good day, I'm trying to make a login screen in php & mysql with Jquery(ajax). but I'm having a problem with if else statement.

Here's my code.

```
    $("#btnLogin").click(function(){
            username=$("#textUsername").val();
            password=$("#textPassword").val();

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "login.php",
                    data: "username="+username+"&password="+password,
                    success: function(result){

                            var res = result;
                            if(res == 'correct'){
                                    alert("success login");
                            } else {
                                    console.log("fail login");
                            }
                    }
            });
             return false;
    });
```

it always fall in else. even the result is return as correct

Comment: `res` never equals `correct`. I'm not sure what help you're expecting here. Have you checked what the value actually is?

Comment: What do you get for `console.log(result);`?

Comment: Also make sure that there is no whitespace / newlines / etc in your output.

Comment: You might also want to pass the data as following: `data: {username: username, password: password},`

Comment: You need to confirm what login.php is returning - it might be a JSON object

Comment: when i try to check the value of result. it returns "correct". exactly what i echo in php.

Comment: @Lestr1992 check my answer and it will solve your problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trailing spaces in Ajax response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232264/trailing-spaces-in-ajax-response)

Comment: thank you so much guys. it works! "var res = $.trim(result);"

Comment: @Lestr1992 happy for you using $.trim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your response may contain spaces. So check what is coming in the response.And its better to trim your response before doing the checking. You can use jquery trim function to remove spaces. Trim the response  **$.trim (result)** and it'll work.

Why the response contain spaces. You can find the answers here

1. [Space Before Ajax Response (jQuery, PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029802/space-before-ajax-response-jquery-php)
2. [strange thing, ajax response includes whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477187/strange-thing-ajax-response-includes-whitespace)
3. [Trailing spaces in Ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232264/trailing-spaces-in-ajax-response)

Comment: @Lestr1992 glad to help bro! Accept my answer to let others know this is done and we can move forward

Comment: This should have been flagged as a duplicate. Your answer was posted before OP had even clarified what the returned `result` was. Answers on StackOverflow should never start with the word "Probably".

Comment: but actually "var res = $.trim(result);" this what i did. but still thank you dude :)

Comment: Just helped the guy solved his problem then someone just downvoted. What a total nonsense.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I know the answer because I had this problem before.

Comment: @JohnRobertson again, you answered before OP had clarified what the returned `result` was. Without knowing that, this problem could have been caused by anything: a PHP error, a JavaScript error, a typo, a missing jQuery library, etc. Now that we do know what the returned `result` is, we can flag this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly And by the way. I answered with probably because there could have been a "PHP error, a JavaScript error, a typo, a missing jQuery library, etc."  as what you said. What a nonsense.

Comment: I think what people are trying to say is that if the question cannot be answered, it is better to request additional information than to post a "shot in the dark" answer. Now it turns out that this shot in the dark actually solved the problem, so @Lestr1992 should upvote and accept this as the correct answer. And please don't down vote posts just because they answer a duplicate question. Instead, close the original question as a duplicate and leave the answers alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add_err").css('display', 'none', 'important');
 $("#login").click(function(){  
      username=$("#name").val();
      password=$("#word").val();
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "login.php",
        data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
       success: function(html){    
        if(html=='true')    {
         //$("#add_err").html("right username or password");
         window.location="dashboard.php";
        }
        else    {
        $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
         $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/alert.png' />Wrong username or password");
        }
       },
       beforeSend:function()
       {
        $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
        $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...")
       }
      });
    return false;
});
```

});

Answer (score -1):

You should trim before comparison

```
     if($.trim(res) == 'correct'){


       }
```