# How To write correct code for Jquery Check, Validate & Redirect on success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I worked for php over last 7-8 years. But i never try ajax, jquery or javascript more then very simply copy-paste work.Now i need jquery for my work.I almost finished all worked except a login with password process. So i try to write php and jquery code for this.

Here is my code:
**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function login() {
            // get values
            var db = $("#db").val();
            var pass = $("#pass").val();
            // Check record
            $.post("check.php", { db: db, pass: pass }, function (data) {
                if (data.status=='s') //status is proper of the json object, which we gave in php code 
                {
                    var form = $('<form action="success.php" method="post">' +
                        '<input type="text" name="db" value="new1" />' +
                        '<input type="text" name="pass" value="12345" />' +
                        '</form>');
                    $('body').append(form);
                    form.submit();
                } else {
                    alert( "status: " + data );
                }
                // close the popup
                $("#pass").modal("hide");
                // clear fields from the popup
                $("#pass").val("");
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body style="color:#ece9e9;background:#184C5D;"><div style="margin-top:25%; margin-left:25%; margin-right:auto;">
    <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "new1";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        echo '<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pass">Login</button><br/><br/>';
        $conn->close();
    ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal - login -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="pass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Enter Password</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pass">Password</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="pass" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <?php  echo '<input type="hidden" name="db" id="db" value="'.$dbname.'">'; ?>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="login()">Login</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <!-- // Modal -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code for **check.php**

```
<?php 
    $server = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "$_POST[db]";
    $pass = "$_POST[pass]";
    $conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $dpass ="";
    $sql = "SELECT pass FROM project WHERE id ='1' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $dpass = $row["pass"];
        }
    } else {}
    if ($pass == $dpass) {
        echo "s";
    } else { 
        echo "xx";
    } 
    $conn->close();
?>
```

My problem is when try with correct password [12345] its showing xx in alert pop. Can anyone find out what i missing? Because i write that jquery code from 3 different source.  in other hand, when i test check.php with a simple post method page, its work. means check.php is ok.

Comment: 7-8 years and you not learnt to write readable code, or look at your browser console for errors. :/

Comment: I've also never seen root database credentials being stored a form.

Comment: unfortunately yes.I love to work on PHP & i can do what i need in php until today.Even i can do that in php,but ajax would be nice for client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jeroen van der Hel said, i've got 2 HTML elements with id="pass". So first i need to change pass to anything, like passtab

```
<div class="modal fade" id="passtab" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

Then main thing is response contain spaces. So i'd to trim response before doing the checking through jquery trim function.

```
if (data.status=='s')
```

to

```
if ($.trim(data) == 's' )
```

Why the response contain spaces. You can find the answers here

1. [Space Before Ajax Response (jQuery, PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029802/space-before-ajax-response-jquery-php)

2.[strange thing, ajax response includes whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477187/strange-thing-ajax-response-includes-whitespace)

3. [Trailing spaces in Ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232264/trailing-spaces-in-ajax-response)

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 HTML elements with id="pass":

line 47:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="pass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

and line 57:

```
<input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="pass" class="form-control" />
```

---

Therefore your var pass from line 8 will take the value of the first element with id 'pass' it will encounter. In this case that will be the div from line 47.

Comment: This is useful but not proper solution. now i can pass variables successfully.But still not able to auto redirect on success.So now problem is in index.php I think still problem on jquery if statement.

Comment: Every things is ok now. only problem is in `if (data.status=='s') { }`  but else is working very well. can anyone solve this?